# convert hex to string in java android

Tags: java, android

i need to convert hex to string in java for android app

http://codebeautify.org/hex-string-converter

i used this to convert but the string is in unreadable form for example

Hex is "6E 0F 00 00" and i need to convert it to String but site shows something which i can not even copy so i want some one to help me to convert the hex to string and show in toast which will show properly no matters what encoding it is

used this but gives force close

```
public void button1(View v){ 

        try {
            String result= new String(decode("6E 0F 00 00"), "UTF-8");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static byte[] decode(String hex){

        String[] list=hex.split("(?<=\\G.{2})");
        ByteBuffer buffer= ByteBuffer.allocate(list.length);
        System.out.println(list.length);
        for(String str: list)
            buffer.put(Byte.parseByte(str,16));

        return buffer.array();

}
```

i get error

03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3680)
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4191)
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17229)
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3675)
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    ... 12 more
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: " 0F 00 00"
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    at java.lang.Byte.parseByte(Byte.java:214)
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    at com.learn.zzz.MainActivity.decode(MainActivity.java:41)
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    at com.learn.zzz.MainActivity.pp(MainActivity.java:26)
03-28 13:59:26.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10044):    ... 15 more

Comment: What's the error? It appears that button1 was supposed to be something like an onClickListener. Given that you don't show code that calls button1, I suspect you made a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: @iheanyi no i use android:onClick method always, on mainactivity.xml put android:onClick:button1 and call button1(View v) you can use your button easy way :)

Comment: Something is wrong with the regular expression in the split. Your error shows that parseByte is trying to parse "0F 00 00" instead of "0F". So, it was able to split off "6E" but not the rest.

Comment: yes but how to fix it no proper solution yet

Comment: I will post a correct solution later today.

Comment: I posted my answer. However, the error you have currently posted should not have been generated by the code that you currently have posted. Make sure you're rebuilding the application.

Comment: 04-03 22:02:46.459: E/AndroidRuntime(10401): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "0F 00 00"  this is making force close now

Comment: There is no way the regex I posted would result in that error. You are doing something else wrong. Did you update the code using my version of the decode method?

Comment: You can post your full code somewhere like pastebin.com (and update your question with a link) and I'll be able to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static byte[] decode(String hex){

        String[] list=hex.split("(?<=\\G.{2})");
        ByteBuffer buffer= ByteBuffer.allocate(list.length);
        System.out.println(list.length);
        for(String str: list)
            buffer.put(Byte.parseByte(str,16));

        return buffer.array();

}

String result= new String(decode("6E 0F 00 00"), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: can you share the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better regex to use: (?<=\G\w{2})(?:\s*)

1. (?<=\G\w{2}) matches an empty string that has the last match followed by two word characters.
2. (?:\s*) a non-capturing match of whitespace.

Note, to properly escape backslash, a second must be inserted in the string literal. That's white the code below has extra backslashes.

Updated decode:

```
public static byte[] decode(String hex) {
    String[] list=hex.split("(?<=\\G\\w{2})(?:\\s*)");
     ByteBuffer buffer= ByteBuffer.allocate(list.length);
     System.out.println(list.length);
     for(String str: list) {
         buffer.put(Byte.parseByte(str,16));
         System.out.println(str);
     }

     return buffer.array();
}
```